# Is there any danger in using an invalid type on an HTML input element?

Tags: html

As I understand it, if an input element contains a type value that isn't recognised by the browser, the browser will treat it as the default value of "text".

As such, is there any danger in using an invalid type?

I won't go into the nuts and bolts, but essentially this is a pseudo-form that is actually converting input to JSON client-side, so the form elements are never actually submitted via post.

But I was concerned about rendering issues - though not encountered any issues.

Comment: for backwards compatibility reasons, yes, an invalid `type` will always give you a text input, so there's no danger... the question is why would you want that?

Comment: if you do select `input[type="text"]` in CSS, it will not work though.